# How to use Rust's iced-x86 to generate opcodes from instructions string

Tags: assembly, rust, disassembly

Im new to Rust and I was messing around with the `iced` library to disassemble stuff and it is extremely useful.

What I can't seem to understand is how to use the `Encoder` to generate opcodes from a *string* and not an `Instruction` struct.

As far as I can tell the `iced-x86` documentations doesnt cover this.

According to the documentation: `The encoder can be used to re-encode decoded instructions at any address` - doesnt say anything about encoding instructions from string

This is what I basically trying to achieve:

```
use iced_x86::*;

let instr = "xchg ah,[rdx+rsi+16h]";

let mut encoder = Encoder::new(64);
match encoder.encode(&instr, 0x5555_5555) {
    Ok(len) => assert_eq!(4, len),
    Err(err) => panic!("{}", err),
}
// We're done, take ownership of the buffer
let buffer = encoder.take_buffer();
assert_eq!(vec![0x86, 0x64, 0x32, 0x16], buffer);
```

Comment: The doc doesn't cover it [because there is not such a feature](https://github.com/0xd4d/iced/issues/77).

Comment: Yes I saw that issue, I was wondering if there is a workaround

Comment: No, of course not. It's a whole feature missing :) But surely there are other assembler libraries that support assembling from a string into a binary buffer. Then you could decode the buffer. Of course, it's hacky and wasteful.